# Using LINQ in ICollection (EF)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, icollection

It happends that in EF you must use ICollection for your properties,

```
eg. public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

But I wan't to use LINQ on that list, which is not possible in ICollection.
Should I cast it to IQueryable? How? or what is the standard way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do linq against an ICollection. What problem are you encountering?

Comment: Are you sure that System.Linq is referenced? Linq works on IEnumerable, which ICollection implements.

Comment: @RyanBennett, I have a feeling that's the issue.

Comment: Sorry I didn't knew that System.Linq had to be referenced... I thought it was integrated with the syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ryan is correct in the comments.

You need to ensure that you reference the Linq namespace.

> using System.Linq;